# Reading parameter descriptions in Julia Documentation

Tags: julia

Compared to the Python documentation, I find that Julia documentation are much harder to read.

For example, the [`rand`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Random/#Base.rand) function:

```
rand([rng=GLOBAL_RNG], [S], [dims...])
```

How should I interpret this? What do the brackets mean? Which parameters are optional, and which are not?

Also, in Flux's documentation for [`Dense`](https://fluxml.ai/Flux.jl/stable/models/layers/#Flux.Dense):

```
Dense(in, out, σ=identity; bias=true, init=glorot_uniform)
```

Why are some parameters separated by commas and others by semicolons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters is square brackets `[]` are optional - this is a convention for documentation across many programming languages - this is not a part of language syntax though. Hence all parameters for `rand` are optional and you can do just `rand`.

Actually it is a good idea to try to type `methods(rand)` in the console to see the huge number of methods required to cover all such use cases:

```
julia> methods(rand)
# 80 methods for generic function "rand":
[1] rand() in Random at c:\Julia-1.7.2\share\julia\stdlib\v1.7\Random\src\Random.jl:257
.....
```

Semicolon is a part of syntax used for separating positional parameters from named parameters in Julia functions.
As an example consider a function:

```
function foo(a, b=4; c, d=8)
   return a+b+c+d
end
```

Than you could do:

```
julia> foo(1,c=100)
113
```